# Go through a column and retrieve unique values and copy them to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I just started a VBA course and I am stuck on something probably simple. Starting with this

[image: sheet]

I am trying find unique combos of letters in a column and copy them to a seperate column. I've used different code, but each time I run it, nothing happens.
What end result should look like

[image: like]

*First attempt*:

```
Sub ModChallenge()
'First step, label our terms

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ticker As String
    
    'Then cycle through all sheets in book
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    
    'Loop for each row to the last row
    For i = 2 To LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'If the row the loop on one doesn't match the one below it, copy it to a cell
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
    
    Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cells(i, 9) = Ticker
 
    Else 

    End If
    Next i
    Next ws  
End Sub
```

*Second Attempt*:

```
Sub ModChallenge()
'First step, label our terms

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Ticker As String
    
    'Then cycle through all sheest in book
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    
    'Loop for each row to the last row
    For i = 2 To LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'If the row the loop on one doesn't match the one below it, copy it to a cell
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
    
    Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

    Else   
   
    End If
    Next i
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not valid VBA.  'For i = 2 To LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row'.  In the VBA IDE put you cursor on the for and press F1.  Please take the time to read up of for loops.

Comment: I cannot understand what you try accomplishing... Based on what to calculate "Yearly Change" and "Percent Change"? The last column, probably summarizes each case of "<vol>" quantities. Then, where the ticker to be processed exist? In all sheets of the workbook?

Comment: If you are just starting VBA then please install the free and fantastic open source Rubberduck addin for VBA.  Pay particular attention to the code inspections.

Comment: For starters, do this first : `LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and then use that variable later.... `For i = 2 To LastRow` - and make sure all your `Range`/`Cells` objects inside the loop are qualified with the `Worksheet` they are from.

Answer (score 1):

### Single-Column Unique Values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RetrieveUniqueValues()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, cell As Range, Data(), rKey
    Dim r As Long, rCount As Long, rString As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Reference the last source cell.
        Set cell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        If cell.Row > 1 Then
            ' Reference the source range.
            Set rg = ws.Range("A2", cell)
            rCount = rg.Rows.Count
            ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
            If rCount = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
            Else
                Data = rg.Value
            End If
            ' Write the unique values from the array to a dictionary.
            For r = 1 To rCount
                rString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
                If Len(rString) > 0 Then
                    dict(rString) = Empty
                End If
            Next r
            rCount = dict.Count
            If rCount > 0 Then
                ' Write the values from the dictionary to the array.
                r = 0
                ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
                For Each rKey In dict.Keys
                    r = r + 1
                    Data(r, 1) = rKey
                Next rKey
            End If
        End If
        dict.RemoveAll
        ' Reference the first destination cell.
        Set cell = ws.Range("I2")
        ' Reference the destination range.
        Set rg = cell.Resize(rCount)
        ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
        rg.Value = Data
        ' Clear below.
        rg.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - rg.Row - r + 1).Offset(r).ClearContents
    Next ws
         
    MsgBox "Unique values retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Microsoft 365**

- In Microsoft 365, it becomes much simpler by using the `Unique` function.
- It will accept an empty string as a unique value though.

```vb
Sub RetrieveUniqueValues365()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, cell As Range, Data(), r As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Reference the last source cell.
        Set cell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        If cell.Row > 1 Then
            ' Reference the source range.
            Set rg = ws.Range("A2", cell)
            r = rg.Rows.Count
            ' Write the unique values from the source range to an array.
            If r = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
            Else
                Data = Application.Unique(rg)
            End If
            r = UBound(Data, 1)
            ' Reference the first destination cell.
            Set cell = ws.Range("I2")
            ' Reference the destination range.
            Set rg = cell.Resize(r)
            ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
            rg.Value = Data
            ' Clear below.
            rg.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - rg.Row - r + 1).Offset(r).ClearContents
        End If
    Next ws
         
    MsgBox "Unique values retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Loop**

- If the data is sorted, and you want to know how this is achieved by using a loop, you could use the following. This will be less efficient (slower) than the previous versions.

```vb
Sub RetrieveUniqueValuesLoop()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, sCell As Range, dCell As Range
    Dim oStr As String, nStr As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Reference the last source cell.
        Set sCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        If sCell.Row > 1 Then
            ' Reference the source range.
            Set rg = ws.Range("A2", sCell)
            ' Reference the first destination cell.
            Set dCell = ws.Range("I2")
            ' Loop through the source cells.
            For Each sCell In rg.Cells
                nStr = CStr(sCell.Value)
                If Len(nStr) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                    If nStr <> oStr Then ' new group
                        dCell.Value = nStr ' write
                        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next destination cell
                        oStr = nStr ' new becomes old
                    End If
                'Else ' is blank; do nothing
                End If
            Next sCell
            ' Clear below.
            dCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - dCell.Row + 1).ClearContents
            oStr = vbNullString ' reset for the next iteration (worksheet)
        'Else ' no data; do nothing
        End If
    Next ws
         
    MsgBox "Unique values retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Excel built in `RemoveDuplicates()` functionality

```
Option Explicit

Sub ModChallenge()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws 'reference current worksheet
            .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=.Range("I2") ' copy referenced worksheet column "A" cells from row 2 down to last not empty one and paste it from range I2 downwards
                .Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo ' remove duplicates from pasted cells
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```